# How to import a project which has only src and res folder

Tags: android, eclipse

I bumped to a basic problem, I downloaded a sample code from Android developers site which had only folders src/ res/ and a manifest file.

While I was trying to import this into eclipse, I keep getting error like
"Select at least one project"

I also tried copying a edited .project file but that didnot help much and still keep seeing the same error.

Can some one help me out of this situation.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Create an emptry project then copy the res, src and manifest to your project manually

Comment: my pleasure :) . you are welcom

Answer (score 0):

Copy your project anywhere except your current work space and follow the steps.

```
Eclipse menu, File --> New --> Project.. --> Android/ Android Project from Existing Code
--> Next --> Browse.. --> Finish.
```

Hope these are very easy steps..:)

Answer (score 0):

Import -> Android -> Existing Android Code into Workspace